# Running rails server within file does not show changes. Perhaps git related

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, github

I'm having a hard time articulating my problem: when running the rails server within a file, the changes I made earlier today are not appearing on my local host. Yet, when I open the file in Sublime it shows that all of my code is there. It was working earlier today. I know it is not a rake database issue as the most recent changes I made to the model are showing up on the local host.

Link to github: https://github.com/BrianLobdell/depot

Please help!

-Brian

Comment: Further tinkering shows that the stylesheet changes show up when I create a new object. However, the 'pre-loaded' objects created in my seeds.rb are no longer showing up.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was run $ rake db:seed. still have no idea why I needed to run it again.